# Will a surface perpendicular to the electric field always be equipotential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, vector-fields

In the figure attached there are four different electric field vectors with different magnitudes, point away from A.

My question is will C be an equipotential surface? i.e. will the potential difference across P1 and P4 be 0?

On moving a charge from P1 to P4 the work done per unit charge by external agent will be $$\,V=-\int E \cdot ds = -\int E\,ds\,cos\theta$$
theta will be 90 degree, so $\,V=0$, i.e. no work has to be done in carrying a charge from P1 to P4

But if we take two charges (of equal magnitude) lying on A (A will also be equipotential), one goes from A to P1 with work done being $W_1$, the other one goes from A to P4 and then to P1 with work done being $W_2$, $\,\,W_1\ne W_2$ because they have moved through different electric fields E1 and E4 to get to C. On A both the charges had equal potentials since A is also an equipotential, but then on C they won't have equal potentials

So will C be an equipotential surface or not?[image]

Edit: I think as Emilio Pisanty stated in the comments, the situation described isn't conservative, which is why i am having the confusion, so my confusion is solved now

Comment: The scenario you describe is unphysical. If the situation is static and the electric fields are parallel, then they *must* have the same magnitude. Otherwise, the field would not be conservative (ie it would have a nonzero curl).

Answer (score 1):

In the case of electrostatic fields indeed equipotential surfaces are perpendicular to the electric field. In other cases the vector potential should also be considered.

Answer (score 0):

All surfaces that are perpendicular to electric field lines will be an equipotential surface.

( Just because im pedantic: Your scenario, placing 2 charges at once will change the resultant field which will change the equipotential surfaces. However I know that is not what you mean. (If there was a single charge placed we obviously ignore the E field of that specific charge and thus the field is the same))

Lines A and C are equipotential lines. A charge moving from  $E_{1}$ to $P_{1,2,3,4}$ will all give the same change in potential energy.

Yes, they experience different paths through the electric field , however the work done by the E field is PATH independant. It doesn't matter what path I take, aslong as the start and end potential for each path is the same, the same amount of work would be done.

In your scenario, $W_{1} = W_{2}$, you are wrong.

Comment: So i have a question, we move a charge from A to P1 through field E1, and another from A to P4 through field E4. A is equipotential, but the work done in moving both charges is different since they are moved through different fields. So once they reach P1 and P4 they have different potentials, so C is not equipotential, where am I wrong?

Comment: "work done in moving both charges is different since they are moved through different fields" the E field in this case is conservative, $\int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl}$  is path independant. It doesn't matter what path you take the work done is invariant.

Comment: As Emilio Pisanty has mentioned, i think the electric field is not conservative, because if you move a charge in a closed loop the work done is not coming out to be zero

Comment: Oh,  I didnt read your assumption that they didn't have the same magnitude.  Potential has no meaning for non Conservative fields. The only conclusions you can draw from those lines, is that no work would be done moving on them.